# Bootstrap - collapse button with data target not working on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap collapse button with data target is working on desktop but it is not working on mobile devices.

HTML:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Button with data-target
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using jquery 1.11.1 and I tryed also version 1.9.1 but nothing. I get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in css. In previous div I had in css float: left; and instead of that I put display: inline-block; and the problem fixed.

That css problem confused me why was that the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-block">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```